# How to fire the PropertyChanged event handler for only one time in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I want the registered event handler for a PropertyChange to fire only once even if the Property is again changed in the EventHandler itself or if even if multiple properties are changed on that object.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        private string _oneTimeFiredPropertyChanged;
        private bool _oneTimeFired = false;
        public string OneTimeFiredPropertyChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return _oneTimeFiredPropertyChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!oneTimeFired)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged("OneTimeFiredPropertyChanged");
                    oneTimeFired = true;
                }
                _oneTimeFiredPropertyChanged = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don not have the source code for the property. Its a third party dll.

Comment: @PuneetDudeja what you can do is use this property to wrap the property in your third party dll.